# Android - Converting string to image

Tags: android, android-image

I need to read the text/string from database and convert them into images. I tried the following code but I am getting only blank images. Please help

```
public Bitmap textAsBitmap(String text, float largest, int textColor) {
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(textColor);
            // int width = (int) (paint.measureText(text) + 0.5f); // round

            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);

            paint.setTextSize(16);
            int width = 400;

            // float baseline = (int) (paint.ascent() + 0.5f) + 3f;
            // int height = (int) ((baseline + paint.descent() + 0.5f) + 3);

            int height = 400;

            Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                    Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
            canvas.drawText(text, 0, 5, paint);
            return image;

        }
```

Comment: Does it work if you set the position-parameters to something like 200,100? (Just making sure that the text won't end up outside the bitmap)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but do you perhaps need to first fill your bitmap with a colour that contrasts with textColor?  This would certainly seem like an important thing to do in any case -- the documentation for createBitmap() does not specify the initial content of the bitmap, so it could theoretically be anything, and may change in future versions of the system.